# What's the difference between SystemParametersInfoA and SystemParametersInfo?

Tags: c++, winapi

Sorry I don't quite understand the difference between the two. When I set my desktop wallpaper, only the one with the A at the end works. However, the other one doesn't give me an error. What's going on?

Comment: This question really should have code, so we can explain why you don't get an error. My bet: there's a `(LPCSTR)` cast which tells the compiler not to report the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SystemParametersInfo` is a macro that expands to either `SystemParametersInfoA` or `SystemParametersInfoW` depending on whether your project is set up to use multi-byte (aka ANSI) or Unicode character set. Many Windows API functions - most that deal with strings - use this pattern.

If `SystemParametersInfo` doesn't work for you, then you are trying to use ANSI strings in a Unicode project, or vice versa.